# Localhost dice "datos incorrectos" login pagina web

Tags: php, html, login, localhost

Estoy haciendo un sitio web con una página de log in, ya tiene conexión a base de datos y si registra a nuevos usuarios pero al momento de loguear se mensaje: "Localhost dice "datos incorrectos""
Es un mensaje de mi archivo php para validar el login, aquí adjunto el código:
No se porque no conecta y aparte eso hace que no pueda hacer log out.

```
"<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../admin/class/Usuario.php';

    $email = (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : null;
    $password = (isset($_REQUEST['password'])) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : null;
    $usuario = new Usuario;
    $usuario->setEmail($email);
    $usuario->setPassword($password);
    $entrar=$usuario->logIn();
    if($entrar==true){
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }
    else{
        echo '<script>
                alert("Datos incorrectos");
                window.location.href="../index.php";
            </script>';
    }
    ?>"
```

Comment: Saludos. Con lo que pones de código solo se puede entender que `$usuario->logIn()` no devuelve `true` o valor que se interprete así. Debes compartir o si por alguna razón no es posible revisar lo que se hace, así como lo que ocurre que no devuelve `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Por la estructura de tu código, aparentemente no tienes problemas de conexión a base de datos, puedo inferir que tu problema viene con el usuario y la clave que estas utilizando para hacer **Login**. Te sugiero revises mayusculas y minusculas y con un usuario y pass super fácil y genérico, es decir.

user: admin@gmail.com pass: 123456

Answer (score 0):

Revise que en la función `logIn();` esté haciendo el return correspondiente y que este return esté como booleano y no como un string. También que en la clase Usuario esté llegando el valor de los datos seteados correctamente.